I tryed to run flutter build apk --release and got this error
AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_local_notifications-16.3.3\android\src\main\java\com\dexterous\flutterlocalnotifications\FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1033: error: reference to bigLargeIcon is ambiguous
bigPictureStyle.bigLargeIcon(null);
^
both method bigLargeIcon(Bitmap) in BigPictureStyle and method bigLargeIcon(Icon) in BigPictureStyle match
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           35.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
i tryed changing the version   flutter_local_notifications: ^16.3.3  its the same issue

Change the latest version of Flutter local Notifications . try Flutter pub cache clean , flutter pub cache repair, flutter pub get . Try again to build release app .

You can fix it by upgrading flutter_local_notifications to 17.2.1, or latest. Because by this version the issue has been fixed

The best way to fix this issue is to update the plugin to the latest version - ^18.0.0.

This issue seems to be caused by an ambiguous method reference in the flutter_local_notifications plugin's Android code, specifically in the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java file. The problem arises because the bigLargeIcon method in the BigPictureStyle class can accept both a Bitmap and an Icon, and the compiler is confused about which one to use.
Here’s how you can approach solving this:
Verify the Issue: The error message is showing that the method bigLargeIcon can accept either a Bitmap or an Icon as its argument, but the code is passing null. The compiler doesn’t know whether to use the Bitmap or Icon version of the method when null is passed.
Explicitly Specify the Type: To resolve the ambiguity, you can modify the code in the plugin by explicitly casting null to either Bitmap or Icon depending on which one you intend to use. However, since the plugin's code is being compiled during the build process, directly editing the plugin's code in the cache may not be a sustainable solution, as any update will overwrite the changes.
Suggested Workaround: You can manually modify the plugin's code in the following file:
AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_local_notifications-16.3.3\android\src\main\java\com\dexterous\flutterlocalnotifications\FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java

Locate the line in question:
bigPictureStyle.bigLargeIcon(null);

You can fix this by explicitly casting null to either Bitmap or Icon. For example, if you want to use Bitmap, change the line to:
bigPictureStyle.bigLargeIcon((Bitmap) null);

Alternatively, if you intend to use Icon, you can cast it as:
bigPictureStyle.bigLargeIcon((Icon) null);

Rebuild the Project: After making the changes, clean and rebuild the project:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build <your-build-type> 

flutter_local_notifications: ^16.3.3  # Change this to the latest version

